# Table Format in C with Significant Figures

Tags: c, output

I am in the process of outputting some results I get from some arrays in C in a nice table format, but I want to cut the value down to 2 digits past the decimal point.

Part of my table code looks something like this (some fake arguments just to get the point across).

```
printf("%15d %15f %15f\n", arr[i], arr2[i], arr3[i])
```

I want to trim some of my `double` variables down so a 55.583159 will just return 55.58 without having to get rid of the double data type. So essentially I'm looking for a way to keep `"%15f"` and also add into it a `"%.2f"` in a nice clean manor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which documentation on printf formatting did you read?

Answer (score 5):

you can combine the output format, so if you want 15 digit width (`%15f`) and 2 places after the decimal (`%.2f`) you can use (`%15.2f`)

```
printf("%15d %15.2f %15.2f\n", arr[i], arr2[i], arr3[i])
```

[this](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_31.htm) explains different formatting well